# Removing element from array causes element duplication in "C"

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic

I am using a function to populate dynamically generated arrays.
But whenever I call the function to delete the first n-elements of the array it causes an element duplication.

> Please Ignore all the things in Portuguese.

I am using this function:

```
float *RemoverElementos(float *V, int *N, int k){
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        V[i] = V[i+1];
    }
    (*N) -= k;
    return V;
}
```

[image]

This function makes duplicate values of the second value of the array and completely removes the last value.

Comment: Need more context. But  i think this `V[i] = V[i+1];` should be `V[i] = V[i+k];` and the conditionf of `for`is `i < *N - k` assuming that `*N` contain the size of the array and `k` number of elements need to be removed.

Comment: It worked, everything is working now!